# How to create automatic touch event in android or a fake call

Tags: android

I was trying to make a fake touch using fake touching co-ordinate x,y manually using the following code below.

```
public void update() {
        View view = new View(this);
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        int metaState = 0;
        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain( downTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                x,
                y,
                metaState
        );
       view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);

    }
 @Override

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {


        Log.e("S","pressed");

        return true;
    }

}
```

Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

As I created a motion event and send it to view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent). Why the onTouchEvent() is not calling.

Is this not the proper way to make a fake call.
I saw some document where setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() is called.

I don't need to execute ontouchlistener. I need to execute onTouchEvent method only.
So is my way is right or is there any way to call onTouchEvent() programmatically.